# View Visible on Screen but didMoveToWindow: etc Never Called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation

I'm using `didMoveToWindow:` to trigger an animation with a custom UICollectionViewCell. Weird thing is... the animation works perfectly (and all the methods that should be called are called) for the 1st and 2nd cells...

... for the 3rd cell, it's displayed, but neither `didMoveToWindow:`, `willMoveToWindow:`, `didMoveToSuperview:` nor `willMoveToSuperview:` is ever called for the 3rd. I even tried `drawRect:` and it's never called either...

I don't understand how it could be drawn on the screen without `drawRect:` being called.

In `drawRect:` I just printed to the log, and then called the super implementation. Even though the log message was never called / printed, doing so did turn the background black (normally it's see through). So that must've... done something..?

*Each cell appears around that location, and then is moved into place. Background signifies the frame of the UICollectionView.. to show everything is in bounds.*

**update:**
I tried using `didAddSubview:`, but same thing... it's only ever called for the first two cells. Though, when the 3rd cell is inserted, and the 2nd is reloaded, and `didAddSubview:` is called for the 2nd... the visible cell count of the collection view is 3.

**update2:**
when I check the view hierarchy via Xcode, it shows all 3 cells as subviews of the collection.... yet somehow it's only calling `addSubview:` `didAddSubview:` for the first two.. bizarre

[image]

Comment: tableviewcell can be reused, if it's already displayed `didMoveToWindow:` or `willMoveToWindow` won't be called because it has been added already.

Comment: sorry I should have added. I watched it create a 3rd object. `initWithFrame:` on the 3rd cell, and `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` on the collection. Also the fact that there are 3 cells on the screen at the same time, there must be at least 3 cells.

Comment: Yeah i missed that too ... all 3 cells are on screens..

Comment: Maybe you can try putting the animation code in cellForRow where (cell==nil) ?

Comment: @GeneCode I was considering starting a timer after `cellForItemAtIndexPath:`, and polling the visible cell count, then when it's added to that array... start the animation (since I can't observe that count in any manner).

Comment: @GeneCode it was an actual bug. filed a report with apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been busy with other work past few days, came back to this problem last night... and magically the bug was gone! (after some accidental refactoring I had done).

Before I was doing a "performBatchUpdates:", where I 1) reloaded the previous cell and 2) inserted the new cell. When I did it this way, the view lifecycle events were never called on the inserted cell (starting with the 3rd cell onward).

When I switched to manually reloading the view of the previous cell (just changing the mask view, so no reason to formally reload the cell) by capturing it with "cellForItemAtIndexPath:", and only doing the insert in the perform batch update... I now receive all the correct view lifecycle events for the inserted cell.

So the bug lies somewhere in there.